# calculate percent difference python

Tags: python, percentage

I am trying to get something to work on a form i am building for my job and it doesn't seem to be working the way i expect it to.

I want to calculate the percent difference between the two fields `ANL_CMA1_NUM_CLOSED_SALES` and `ANL_CMA2_NUM_CLOSED_SALES`.

I thought my math was correct but i am only getting results in single digits, either positive or negative depending on the inputted values.

I am working on a form where i can customize permission level and rounding, and i am rounding this to the nearest hundredth.  Can anyone help me with this one?

The original formula did not have the `-100) * 100)` portion at the end of it but also did not work properly.

```
FormSet.SetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CHG_NUM_CLOSED_SALES", 
(((FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA2_NUM_CLOSED_SALES") - 
FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA1_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")) /    
 FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA1_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")) -100) * 100)
```

Comment: just fyi - i dont care about getting all positive results, negative numbers are ok too.

Comment: why am i getting a down vote for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be using integer division (ie, 1/3 == 0) where you need floating-point division (ie 1./3 == 0.3333333).

It may also be easier to understand if you break it up a bit -

```
cma1 = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA1_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")
cma2 = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA2_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")
delta = float(cma2 - cma1) / cma1
FormSet.SetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CHG_NUM_CLOSED_SALES", delta*100.0)
```

Comment: that does make sense! why didnt i think of that!? im still pretty new to python and forgot about how numbers work! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the values to `float` in order to get floating-point division (otherwise, Python does integer division which truncates the result to an integer).

Using temporary variables for sanity:

```
cma1_closed_sales = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA1_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")
cma2_closed_sales = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CMA2_NUM_CLOSED_SALES")
pct_change = 100.0 * (cma2_closed_sales - cma1_closed_sales) / float(cma1_closed_sales)
FormSet.SetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "ANL_CHG_NUM_CLOSED_SALES", pct_change)
```